# Locally Riemannian Homogeneous Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, surfaces, geometric-topology

A Riemannian manifold $ M' $ is Riemannian homogeneous if $ Iso(M') $ acts transitively.

A Riemannian manifold $ M $ is locally Riemannian homogeneous if there exists a Riemannian homogeneous manifold $ M' $ such that
$$
M \cong \Gamma\backslash M'
$$
where $ \Gamma $ is a discrete subgroup of $ Iso(M') $.

Every orientable surface admits a locally Riemannian homogeneous structure (moreover locally symmetric moreover constant curvature).

For the non orientable case I know that the projective plane is Riemannian homogeneous, while connected sums of multiple projective planes are never Riemannian homogeneous. But what about locally Riemannian homogeneous? For example

**Can the connected sum of 3 projective planes be given a locally Riemannian homogeneous structure?**

Comment: Every connected smooth surface admits a complete metric of constant curvature, and is a quotient $\Gamma\backslash M'$, but this is not easy to prove.

Comment: Very cool fact! That's ok you don't have to prove it. I would be satisfied with just knowing an explicit description of $ \Gamma $ as a subgroup of $ Iso(M') $ for the connected sum of 3 projective planes. What is $ Iso(M') $? Is it $ O_{2,1}(\mathbb{R})$? When $ M' $ is simply connected then abstractly $ \Gamma \cong \pi_1(M) $. But if $ Iso(M') $ can be realized as a matrix group I am interested in **an explicit generating set of matrices for $ \Gamma $** for the case of $ M $ a connected sum of three projective planes